# When magic_quotes_gpc ON Apache Xampp Shutdown

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I know there are many possible answers of this question but this happened to me and still not resolve so i wanna know why. I am sorry if this question is too broad.

I am using Win 10 and XAMPP Control Panel V3.2.2. No Skype or any port 80 application running. To stop sql injection I just turn ON magic_quotes_gpc in php.ini file and restart the server but its not running instead it shows the error and Windows Error Message appears "Apache HTTP Stopped Working". When i turn it off it goes back to normal and XAMPP is running. I want to modify the php.ini file without shutting down the XAMPP. Any help .?

Error Appear in XAMPP:

```
12:10:15 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:10:15 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:10:15 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:10:15 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:10:15 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:10:15 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:10:15 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: See [this info](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) ... the `magic_quotes_gpc` was removed in PHP 5.4. The information there is a bit dated, but the other solutions to prevent SQL injection are prepared queries using either **PDO** or **mysqli**.